# Angular 9 Unit Test Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I cannot remove this karma error which claims about the http module, I have tried various ways and I cannot solve it. My application is in angular 9

[image: Report]

Project structure:

app
   Components
       Login.component.ts
       Login.component.spec.ts
   Services
       Login.service.ts
       Login.service.spec.ts

The services services are added in the file app.module.ts

Grettings!

[This is my Login.service.spec.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMe5J.png)

Comment: Try adding HttpClient along with your loginService in providers array of your spec TestModule

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests
https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-http-services

Comment: How to add an inline image.  Copy and paste in the body. Windows has an inbuilt hotkey which executes Snipping Tool. Any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding HttpClient in the providers of your TestBed configuration.. All your test cases mutually exclusive from the application so you have nothing to do with app.module.ts.

Try this.

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
         HttpClient
      ]
     });

OR else try this https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides a test version of the HttpClientModule that you can use in your tests. It makes sure the Http requests does not actually run when your tests run. You add it in the imports array of your Testbed like:

`imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]`